# Jekyll 0.0.0.0 - How to open from mobile device?

Tags: jekyll

when i run my jekyll server on my pc like this : "jekyll serve --host=0.0.0.0",
I dont know how to open this site from my mobile device.
I tried this already (port is 8000):

- localhost
- localhost:8000
- 0.0.0.0
- 0.0.0.0:8000
- 192.168.178.XY (my PCs IP)
- 192.168.178.XY:8000

Comment: Why are you running with host=0.0.0.0? There should be no need for that

Comment: in order to have access from all devices in the wifi network. How shoud i do it otherwise?

Comment: Umm that's not needed. Serving without will work fine. Just tried it on my own, and I can visit myPcIP:8000 on my phone

Answer (score 1):

Run without the `--host=0.0.0.0` flag. You can then visit it on the port you set or default port and your pc's ip.

Bonus: use --watch to make it rebuild if you change a file.

Comment: Not for me. My PCs ip is 192.168.178.xy. When I try 192.168.178.xy:8000 on my phone, it doesnt work. No matter whether i use --host or not

Comment: Ah, just checked my powershell config, I have jekyll serve bound to `jekyll serve -H 0.0.0.0`, does that work?

Comment: What's the Jekyll output when you run it? Worst case scenario, you could just run Jekyll build and use node-live-server or browsersync to serve it.

Comment: You can see it as an answer

Comment: Weird. I get the exact same log, barring the win32 gem bit. Perhaps consider just using node-live-server and Jekyll build?